# Update Quantity In Cart Using Dropdown List

Tags: expresso-store, shopping-cart

I need to display my cart when the cart button is clicked, allowing the user to update the quantity of the items in his cart using a dropdown list. I can get the amount of items he chose to add to his cart using the {item_qty} tag, but how do I display this in a dropdownlist (with the maximum number as the total in stock)?

i.e. if the re are 4 items in stock, the dropdownlist should display options 1 - 4.

My code so far:

```
<select name="items[{key}][item_qty]">
    <option value="{item_qty}">{item_qty}</option>
</select>
```

This displays a dropdownlist with one value (1), but need to display the total in stock.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going to be a bit trickier than that because when you move to the checkout you use the `Checkout` tags instead of the `Product` tag. The difference is that in the `Product` tag `item_qty` represents the number of items the user wants to buy. In the `Checkout` tag `item_qty` represents how many items the user has in their cart. There's not really a ready-made way to do that so you'd need to run a separate query on the product inventory and then use that to populate the drop-down list.